# AzureDevOps pipeline loading file from external source

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hello dear Stack community,

I am looking for solution for my test execution. I am using Java & Selenium & TestNG tests kept on AzureDevOps.

Each execution needs to load input data from file stored in external source - where client have an access and can easily drag-drop files.
By now files are stored on my companys Share Drive. **It works all fine when I run tests from local machine, but when using pipeline, I get FileNotFoundException in line where file is loaded.**

Does anyone have an idea why does it happen and how can it be overcome?
Of course if there is any other solution, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: The pipeline is not your local machine so that's not a guarantee it should work. Did you verify you get the correct connection to the shared drive and your looking in the correct location?

Comment: Hi Bart,
Yes I am sure location is right. If it is OK for local execution, it must work for remote too. To be honest I don't know how to verify whether connection is correct - and how to set it properly. I am very newbie in this :/

Comment: I would setup a very lightweight pipeline to test the connection etc. Just use simple Bash or Powershell tasks to verify conditions you need. Good chance that you cannot reach the company shared drive from a pipeline or it needs additional configuration

Answer (score 1):

> > It works all fine when I run tests from local machine, but when using pipeline, I get FileNotFoundException in line where file is loaded.

If you use Microsoft-hosted agents to access to files, which are stored on company's Share Drive, you should check whether there is correct connection. If your organization is secured with a firewall or proxy server, you need to add certain IP addresses and domain URLs to the allowlist. See: [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops) for details.

Also you could use [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to access to this shared files so it will communicate with company's Share Drive via your internal network.

Comment: Hi Shazin, How about this issue? Please check my answer and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Hello Edward. I will reply as soon as possible with results. I have just came back to work after long weekend (bank holiday in my country). I will simply edit this comment.

Comment: Hi Shazin, How about this issue? Please check my answer and kindly let me know the result.